# Basic Generic DAO based on Reflection

Tags: java, hibernate, reflection, dao

Well, there's something bugging me in my project. I have lots and lots of hibernate entity classes and each one of them have their own DAO (inherited from a GenericDAO). Most of them have no specific funtion, being just an empty class inheriting GenericDAO.

Since I believe that those were unnecessary classes, I decided to get rid of them using reflection.
After some coding, my call on all of those classes that have no specific methods apart from GenericDAO follow this design:

```
DAO.forClass(MyClass.class, MyClassPK.class).genericDAOMethod();
```

It works like a charm. I'm now rid of empty DAOs. But after searching through internet, I have found low to no solution like mine, so the question is:

is this approach wrong or bad in any considerable way? Why no one ever consider doing something like this?

Comment: Can you show how this is using reflection?  Just having a reference to a class is not enough to call this reflection, I think.  I think you could just work with GenericDao<MyClass> on the calling side, and generate those daos in your dependency injection system (assuming you have one).

Comment: My GenericDAO uses Hibernate, so i just need to instantiate a new GenericDAO passing the MyClass and MyClassPK. I do not use CDI in this kind of DAO. In other words, the GenericDAO class declaration is something like this: public class GenericDAO<E,PK>.

Answer (score 5):

Reflection is almost never considered the answer to a problem. Its just hard to read because a lot of people don't know what it is and people that come behind you to modify your code cannot understand it easily. Its not "self-documenting" to use a term from the book Code Complete.

Reflection is powerful, as you just found out doing it to implement a DAO. But you should just be weary of it. A term we use around my office is "code stink", which is code that might be there for specific purpose, but shouldn't be used everywhere unless absolutely needed. Make sure to documented properly so that people that do actually come behind you will know what the heck it is.

I like to use it to write jUnit tests in Spring to compare two objects from two different databases using reflection. But that's a test and isn't actually in production code.

Hope this helps and is kind of what you are looking for!

Comment: Not saying that you will have two different approaches to classes which have own methods and those which do not.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! As I said, this class only resolves the problem of implementing empty DAOs just for the sake of inheritance. In all other situations my desing is trash. I have left it documented in the class... Anyway, your view of reflection-problem-solving is good... i'll pick other views and try to diminize them with good documentation.

Comment: @Dmytro Its the same object type, the databases have essentially the same table in them, so you use reflection to compare the information in the tables. Its the exact same information, same number of fields and everything. Because of this, reflection can be useful here.

Comment: @Dmytro, in my case this class is useful, I have tons os "empty DAOs" and really little business related DAOs.

Comment: @Dalton look there are several aspects of code. One is pure **programming**. And another one is **development**. From **programming** point of view it is OK. But considering **development** for instance future changes, other developers involvement, etc. it is not OK. Hope it makes my point clear.